# Time complexity of a problem inspired by palindromes

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, strings

**This was inspired by Bradshaw's question originally posted on [Math.SatckExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1406146/arranging-a-set-of-strings-to-form-a-palindrome-np-complete)**.

**EVEN PALINDROME**:

**Input**: Given a list of strings $[v_1, v_2, ... ,v_n]$ where $\Sigma |v_i| $ is even number.

**Question**: Is there a permutation $\sigma$ such that $w=v_{\sigma(1)}v_{\sigma(2)}... v_{\sigma(n)}$ $\in \{uu^R \in \Sigma^* \}$.

> Is it NP-complete to determine if a given set of strings can be ordered to form a palindrome (of even length as defined above)? If yes, Is it still NP-complete for $|\Sigma|=2$?

**EDIT**: Marzio has given an elegant reduction which shows that Even Palindrome is NP-complete for binary alphabets.

Comment: @Raphael The suggested reduction from partition is not suitable since reversing the digits of a number would change the value.

Comment: Ouch ... the downvote suggests that there is a much simpler solution than mine ... ?!?  ;-) :-D

Comment: @Vor What could be simpler than polynomial time algorithm? :)

Comment: @MohammadAl-Turkistany P offers rich levels of complexity, and simplicity is completely orthogonal.

Comment: How is this different from the question on Math.SE?  What did you try?  Did you try working through the approach suggested there, as I [previously suggested](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/57192/arranging-a-set-of-strings-to-form-a-palindrome-is-it-np-complete#comment121146_57192) you could make the question better (by showing your work)?   Does that approach have problems, and if so, what are they?

Comment: @D.W.  This problem is different since it addresses only even palindromes. The suggested ideas on  Math SE are not correct since they do not give a correct Karp reduction.

Comment: Perhaps you could identify in the question where the error is or why they do not give a correct reduction.

Comment: @D.W. It is not proper reduction since he is NOT reducing from an NP-complete problem.

Comment: @MohammadAl-Turkistany, I understand, but the comment under that answer claims that applying those same ideas but reducing from Partition should work.  So, does it?

Comment: @D.W. I think that it's unlikely that Partition can work because it is not strongly NP-complete.

Comment: I think I got it ... see my modified answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a wrong polynomial-time attempt, this is a more robust idea to prove that the problem is indeed NP-complete.

The reduction is from the [3-PARTITION problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem) which is **strongly** NP-complete; i.e. it is still NP-complete even if the numbers are represented in unary.

The problem is to decide whether a given multiset $S = \{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\}$ of $n = 3 m$ positive integers, can $S$ be partitioned into $m$ triplets $S_1, S_2, ..., S_m$ such that the sum of the numbers in each subset is equal?

Let $p = (\sum_i a_i) / m$

Note that the problem remains strongly NP-complete even if $p/4 < a_i < p/2$ (which forces each $S_i$ to contain at exactly three elements); see the original definition of 3-PARTITION in Garey&Johnson, Computers and Intractability.

We can build an equivalent EVEN PALINDROME instance in this way:

We add the long string:

$$w = 1 \, 0^p \, 111 \, 0^p 11111 \, 0^p \, ... \, 0^p \, 1^{2m+1}$$

Then we add $n$ more strings:

$$v_i = 0^{a_i}\; , \;i = 1...n$$

and $1 + 3 + 5 + (2m+1) = \sum_{j=1}^{m+1} (2j-1)$ strings of length 1:

$$r_k = 1 \; , \; k = 1...\sum_{j=1}^{m+1} (2j-1)$$

Note that $|w| = \sum_{i=1}^n |v_i| + \sum_k |r_k|$

Proof:

By construction the $w$ contains substrings of odd increasing length $(1,111,11111, ...)$, so it cannot be "placed" in the middle of $u u^R$; but it must be placed entirely in $u$ or entirely in $u^R$ (without loss of generality suppose that it is placed in $u$.

Now the others $v_i$ must be arranged in the opposite part $u^R$ and in such a way that every $p$ zeroes (that can be "totalized" using the $v_i$) an odd number of the $r_k$ can be placed (to reflect the corresponding $1^{2j+1}$ substring of $w$). Furthermore all elements must be placed, so exactly 3 $v_i$ must be picked to reflect each of the $0^p$ substring of $w$. So if an EVEN PALINDROME can be found it induces a valid 3-partition of the $a_i$ of the original problem.

The opposite direction (a 3-partition exists $\Rightarrow$ there is an EVEN PALINDROME is immediate by construction).

Example:

3-Partition instance: $S = \{1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3 \}$, strongly NP-complete; so we can also represent the numbers in unary: $S' = \{ 1_1, 1_1, 1_1, 11_1, 11_1, 111_1 \}$

EVEN PALINDROME reduction:

$w = 1000001110000011111$

$v_i = \{ 0, 0, 0, 00, 00, 000 \}$

$r_k = \{ 1,\quad 1,1,1,\quad 1,1,1,1,1 \}$

Solution of EVEN PALINDROME:

$$uu^R = 1000001110000011111 \quad 11111 \; 0 \; 00 \; 00 \; 111 \; 000 \; 0\; 0\; 1\}$$

which corresponds to the 3-partition:

$S_1 = \{ 1, 2, 2 \}, S_2 = \{ 3, 1, 1 \}$

Comment: Does this reduction also proof NP-completeness if we require  $w \in \{uu \in \Sigma^* \}$?

Comment: @MohammadAl-Turkistany: yes the construction is similar.

Comment: But I guess you we need to change W. Right?

Comment: @MohammadAl-Turkistany: no, unless I'm missing something, $w$ is the same (and the reduction is ultimately the same).

Comment: Is W still forced to be entirely in one half?

Comment: @MohammadAl-Turkistany: yes, it could be right half or left half, but the increasing unary markers $1^i$ forbid the half of the final string to be placed in the middle of $w$.

Comment: @D.W. : the problem remains NP-complete when every integer in S is strictly between p/4 and p/2 (see G&J)

Comment: @Vor Is it strongly NP-complete if every integer is strictly between p/4 and p/2? In addition, I think this point is a key point thus should be added to the answer.

Comment: @xskxzr: the constraint is embedded in the original G&J definition of 3-partition; and it is easy to build a reduction from the unconstrained version (just set $a_j' = a_j + max(a_i) + 1$ and $p' =3(max( a_i ) + 1)+p$) which doesn't "break" the strongly np-completeness. In every case I'll update the answer.